# how to listen for multiple else if statements

Tags: android

my app receives SMS, reads the string, and performs a special action for every string. this works fine if i send a single string in one SMS. However, i want it to be able to work with multiple strings in a single SMS.

```
if (message.toLowerCase().contains("silent")) {
                    silent(context);
                } else if (message.toLowerCase().contains(
                        "loud")) {
                    loud(context);
                } else if (message.toLowerCase().contains("mute")) {
                    mute(context);
```

i want it to launch both `loud(context);` and `mute(context);` if my SMS contains both the strings.

Comment: wait! wtf why the down vote?

Comment: vote down because that's basic program flow you don't know how to implement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to your question my friend is in flow of program :

```
if (message.toLowerCase().contains("silent")) {
                    silent(context);
                } 
if (message.toLowerCase().contains(
                        "loud")) {
                    loud(context);
                } 
if (message.toLowerCase().contains("mute")) {
                    mute(context);
    }
```

That's how it check all the cases :)

Comment: well it means my question was helpful was well